# How to setup order create webhook in shopify?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, webhooks, remix.run

I have started building an application on [shopify-app-remix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/shopify-app-remix). I cannot set up an order to create a webhook on this package. I have tried the below code to fire a webhook when an order is made. when i run the application with `npm run dev` that time in command prompt i can see only "app uninstaller".

In the shopify.server.js file:-

```
import "@shopify/shopify-app-remix/adapters/node";
import {
  AppDistribution,
  DeliveryMethod,
  shopifyApp,
  LATEST_API_VERSION,
} from "@shopify/shopify-app-remix/server";
import { PrismaSessionStorage } from "@shopify/shopify-app-session-storage-prisma";
import { restResources } from "@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2023-07";

import prisma from "./db.server";

const shopify = shopifyApp({
  apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  apiSecretKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET || "",
  apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
  scopes: process.env.SCOPES?.split(","),
  appUrl: process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL || "",
  authPathPrefix: "/auth",
  sessionStorage: new PrismaSessionStorage(prisma),
  distribution: AppDistribution.AppStore,
  restResources,
  webhooks: {
    APP_UNINSTALLED: {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: "/webhooks",
    },
    ORDERS_CREATE: {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: "/webhooks",
    },
  },
  hooks: {
    afterAuth: async ({ session }) => {
      shopify.registerWebhooks({ session });
    },
  },
  ...(process.env.SHOP_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
    ? { customShopDomains: [process.env.SHOP_CUSTOM_DOMAIN] }
    : {}),
});

export default shopify;
export const apiVersion = LATEST_API_VERSION;
export const addDocumentResponseHeaders = shopify.addDocumentResponseHeaders;
export const authenticate = shopify.authenticate;
export const unauthenticated = shopify.unauthenticated;
export const login = shopify.login;
export const registerWebhooks = shopify.registerWebhooks;
export const sessionStorage = shopify.sessionStorage;
```

In the webhooks.jsx file:-

```
import { authenticate } from "../shopify.server";
import db from "../db.server";

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const { topic, shop, session } = await authenticate.webhook(request);

  switch (topic) {
    case "APP_UNINSTALLED":
      if (session) {
        await db.session.deleteMany({ where: { shop } });
      }
      break;
    case "CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST":
    case "CUSTOMERS_REDACT":
    case "SHOP_REDACT":
    case "ORDERS_CREATE": console.log(' Order create webhook run'); break;
    default:
      throw new Response("Unhandled webhook topic", { status: 404 });
  }

  throw new Response();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

correct name for order/create webhook is ORDER_TRANSACTIONS_CREATE

According to this documentation.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-07/enums/WebhookSubscriptionTopic

Comment: These docs include ORDER_TRANSACTIONS_CREATE and ORDERS_CREATE topics. Both are valid webhook subscription topics but likely have different payloads.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Change the app's access scopes, request access to protected customer data, and reinstall the app on the development/Shopify store that it's connected to.

Through trial and error, I set up the order/create webhook from the `shopify-app-remix` template app with the following steps. Several things need to be done to get this webhook subscription to register.
The only change you should make in the code you provided is in the `webhook.jsx` file:

```js
switch (topic) {
    case "APP_UNINSTALLED":
      if (session) {
        await db.session.deleteMany({ where: { shop } });
      }
      break;
    case "ORDERS_CREATE": 
      console.log(' Order create webhook run'); 
      break; // <-- self-contained case logic
    // The following cases funnel to the default response throw
    // until they are given their custom logic to carry out...
    case "CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST":
    case "CUSTOMERS_REDACT":
    case "SHOP_REDACT":
    default:
      throw new Response("Unhandled webhook topic", { status: 404 });
  }

  throw new Response();
```

Move the switch case for `ORDERS_CREATE` up to allow the "default" cases (`CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST`, `CUSTOMERS_REDACT`, and `SHOP_REDACT`) to flow as intended through the switch statement. With what you posted, those 3 other cases would print the `ORDERS_CREATE` console statement and break without hitting the default response.

To subscribe to the `ORDERS_CREATE` webhook topic, you will need to request access to protected customer data for your app to receive order payloads. See the [shopify.dev docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/store/data-protection/protected-customer-data#request-access-to-protected-customer-data) on the subject, which guides you through the Shopify Partners dashboard to do this.

In addition to the protected customer data access request, you will need to add a new scope to the `Shopify.app.toml` file found at the root of the app template:

```ini
[access_scopes]
# Learn more at https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/configuration#access_scopes
scopes = "write_products,read_orders" # <-- ",read_orders" added
```

The current template only includes the `write_products` scope by default but per the [`shopify.dev` webhook subscription topic docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/enums/WebhookSubscriptionTopic#value-orderscreate-orderscreate) you can use either `read_orders` or `read_marketplace_orders` scopes to subscribe to `ORDERS_CREATE`. After adding one of these options to the access scopes, the app must be reinstalled to the development store that it is connected to. One way to do this is to utilize the Shopify CLI to uninstall/reinstall and kick on the development server with one nifty command:

```bash
> npm run dev --reset
```

The `--reset` flag will be passed to the `shopify app dev` command that `npm run dev` invokes. This should maintain the access scopes that you add to the TOML file, whereas running `npm run dev` would overwrite the access scopes back to the default `write_products`, and the webhook would continue to be unregistered.

This will prompt you with 2 questions to reconnect:

```bash
Before proceeding, your project needs to be associated with an app.

?  Create this project as a new app on Shopify?
✔  No, connect it to an existing app

?  Which existing app is this for?
✔  MyShopifyRemixApp (shopify.app.toml)
```

These steps should achieve the desired results from the base `shopify-app-remix` template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest Shopify Boiler plate produced by the CLI.

Additional webhooks are created on the initial install. Even if it was correctly installed, relying on this isn't advised.

In the long run, you'll want to develop methods to add the webhooks yourself.

- What if your app grows and you require more webhooks
- What if your app crashed and Shopify removed your webhooks.

Here is the official documentation https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/guides/webhooks.md

Comment: That repository was since changed and the readme you linked is no longer there.